# How to print 1 ,2,3..10 number in one column using sql query

Tags: sql

I am using 11g RDBMS and in one interview interviewer ask me that print 1 to 10 numbers using SQL query don't use loop if you are using PLSQL, means using select query he wants to see the result.

like Table:
     1
     2
     3

Comment: care to explain why?

Comment: If you don't want loop, then print 1, 2, 3, ...., 10. ;)

Comment: Depends on your database system, but use ROW_NUMBER() or equivalent on a table with at least 10 rows

Comment: I need  to create 1 query in sql which will give you the number in 1 column from 1 to 10.

Comment: I can't use Print for this,it is not an option.

Comment: 11g we are using.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches, both are SQL Server syntax, but you will find something similar for other RDBMs:

--`ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.objects; --any table with more rows than 10 will do
```

--recursive CTE

```
WITH recursiveCounter AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Nr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Nr+1 
    FROM recursiveCounter AS r
    WHERE r.Nr<10
) 
SELECT * FROM recursiveCounter
```